# How to connect mongodb from aws ec2 ubuntu docker containers?

Tags: mongodb, aws, docker, containers

I have tried

```
mongosqld --addr localhost:3002 --mongo-uri xxxxx.com:27017
```

But it is throwing the following error:

> unable to load MongoDB information:
>
> failed to create admin session for loading server cluster information: unable to execute command: server selection error: server selection timeout current topology: Type: Unknown